# How To Buy Bitcoins On BTC-e (USA)

Tags: exchanges, btce, money-transfer

BTC-e doesn't appear to allow USA wires from banks, and it has other options like MoneyPolo or OKPAY, neither of which allow USA customers either.  I've seen bitcoin traders arbitrage trade using US Dollars with BTC-e and they are Americans, so I'm curious how Americans use BTC-e outside of transferring bitcoin from one site to BTC-e?

Answer (score 1):

BTC-E shut down by government and it won't come back. So there's no way to do that.
[image]
<sub>(source: [btc-e.com](https://btc-e.com/banner.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can either fund your account with btc directly, or if you must deposit usd, you can wire the money (with a hefty fee). http://support.btc-e.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/204/26/deposits

I recommend buying your btc at a dealer like coinbase.com, which you can setup to withdrawal  from your bank. Then transfer the btc to btc-e to trade.

Edit: arbitrage with the same "pool" of money is not very easy. Like you say, you have to withdrawal usd at some point to send it to another exchange which could take days to clear. Arbitrage is done with two or more "pools" of money, one on each exchange. You don't move the usd back and forth (you can move the btc much more easily, but that's only arbitrage one way). The gains from arb'ing are a net sum value of all pools of money. Or you can take short positions on the higher priced exchange and long positions on the lower priced exchange, hoping they meet in the middle.

Comment: Thanks, I discovered that I can't wire funds to BTC-e from a US bank.  Also, for reasons I'm not sure of, the US doesn't allow MoneyPolo, OKPAY or the other electronic options that BTC-e uses, and BTC-e doesn't appear to use PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you used btc-e-codes? It's like real cash, but only in exchange. On BTC-e avalibale codes for RUR-rubles, EUR-euros and USD-US dollars.